# What's the penalty for exceeding 250 kts below 10,000 ft MSL without authorization?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspeed

What if any enforcement actions by the FAA are likely for exceeding the 250 KIAS limitation below 10,000 ft MSL?

Comment: The question does might match the title. "What is the established penalty" and "how likely is it for that penalty to be enforced" are quite different.

Comment: You are penalized 15 knots and 1000 feet. </grin>

Comment: Perhaps you mean what’s the penalty for being caught exceeding 250 kts…   ;-)

Comment: @Jim, that in itself would probably violate something here, lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Without authorization" depends if the flight is controlled or uncontrolled.

- If controlled, the ATC will request the proper speed (if the exceedance is big enough to be noticeable and to matter), and if there is repeated noncompliance (i.e. to the ATC's instruction) that isn't due to an emergency (or performance limitation, e.g. heavily-loaded 747s routinely and legally* exceed 250 knots on departure due to their high *V2 plus* speeds), then it will be reported.

> * (d) If the minimum safe airspeed for any particular operation is greater than the maximum speed prescribed in this section, the aircraft may be operated at that minimum speed. ([14 CFR § 91.117](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.117))

- If uncontrolled, someone *somehow* needs to notice it and report it (perhaps the alleged offender *did* have authorization).

---

In all cases, the FAA's course of action is generally:

> 1. Informal Procedures and Settlements
> 2. Certificate Actions
> 3. Civil Penalty Actions
>
> — [Legal Enforcement Actions](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/enforcement/enforcement_actions), faa.gov

From FAA Order [2150.3C with Change 7](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentid/1034329) (the latest as of writing this), exceeding speed and deviating from ATC, both are **severity level 1** (see PDF page 219):

> [image]

And on page 207:

> [image]

(Note: The PDF is corrupted when searching for things in tables; I can't copy as text as it results in "���...".)

---

Example story: *[Air Force jets that buzzed Charlotte were 'careless and reckless,' FAA report says](https://www.wbtv.com/story/33728349/air-force-jets-that-buzzed-charlotte-were-careless-and-reckless-faa-report-says/),* wbtv.com (though in *this* case the findings are sent over to the USAF)